# pydev data not uploading on postgres

Tags: python, eclipse, postgresql, pydev

My code functions and indentations are correct on eclipse. When running, it displays "Error %s % e" but when I go to postgresql the data doesn't upload there in anyway whatsoever. What should I do?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2
import sys


con = None

try:
    con = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='test123' user='postgres' password='XXX'")   
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Products(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(20), Price INT)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(1,'Milk',5)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(2,'Sugar',7)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(3,'Coffee',3)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(4,'Bread',5)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products VALUES(5,'Oranges',3)")
    con.commit()
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
if con:
    con.rollback()

print ("Error %s % e")
sys.exit(1)

finally:   
    if con:
        con.close()
```

Comment: Your `except` is indented incorrectly.

Comment: it is indented correctly on my eclipse. What's the next step?

Comment: The code in your question is incorrectly indented, then, and your `except`/`if`condition is incorrect. Please correct that. If not, most answers you will get, will point out that error.

Comment: What I meant to say is that on my pydev module the indentations are correct. Problem was that I was connected to the default server and did not create a localhost on Pgadmin4 as I should have. Now it's all good :) Thanks!